# JOM files not being generated

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I'm porting a qt project that compiles on a MacOS to Windows. I've managed to more or less fix all of the compiler errors, but I'm now met with this:

```
18 warnings generated.
      /OUT:debug\editor.exe @C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\editor.exe.10472.84781.jom
The system cannot find the path specified.
jom: C:\Source\build-project-qt-Desktop_Qt_5_12_9_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\src\Makefile.Debug [debug\editor.exe] Error 1
jom: C:\Source\build-project-qt-Desktop_Qt_5_12_9_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\src\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Source\build-project-qt-Desktop_Qt_5_12_9_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
02:32:53: The process "C:\Users\User\msvc_make.bat" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.9 MSVC2017 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

I've been looking for hours and I have no idea why this isn't being generated. I would very much like to not disable JOM if I don't have to (not that I haven't tried, setting CMake generator in the kit to `NMake Makefiles with Codeblock` instead of `NMake Makefiles JOM with Codeblocks` just gives me the same error).

EDIT: This is the part of the Makefile.debug file which seems to invoke the editor.exe:

```
####### Build rules

first: all
all: Makefile.Debug  debug\editor.exe

debug\editor.exe: C:\Source\build-project-Desktop_Qt_5_12_9_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\src\..\lib\cocos2d\debug\cocos2d.lib C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5OpenGLd.lib C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Guid.lib C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Xmld.lib C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Cored.lib C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\msvc2017_64\lib\qtmaind.lib ui_mainwindow.h ui_setprojectpathdialog.h $(OBJECTS) 
    $(LIBAPP) $(LIBFLAGS) /OUT:$(DESTDIR_TARGET) @<<
      [here is a list of paths to a bunch of obj files in a debug folder]
<<
```

Here are the variables I was able to find:

```
DESTDIR        = debug\ #avoid trailing-slash linebreak
TARGET         = editor.exe
DESTDIR_TARGET = debug\editor.exe
```

`OBJECTS` is a list of obj files in the debug folder.

Comment: That prefix `/OUT:` looks wrong to me.  Either there's supposed to be some other program provided which is missing, or that prefix should not be there.  Unfortunately nmake is not a great implementation of make (it doesn't even try to be standard and lacks helpful error output).  I think you'll have to go look in the `src\Makefile.Debug` file and try to find the rule that invokes `editor.exe`, and copy/paste that rule into your question.  Else maybe the `qmake` or `qt` folks can give you some tips without that.

Comment: @MadScientist I wholeheartedly agree. I've updated my question. These is no mention of any jom files there.

Comment: It looks like make variables `LIBAPP` and `LIBFLAGS` are empty or unset.  `LIBAPP`, at least, needs to designate a program appropriate for building the target.

Comment: Also, I'm inclined to agree with @MadScientist that the `/OUT` flag looks suspicious.  From its name I infer that it is meant to specify a directory or full pathname for the created file, but it's unclear how variable `DESTDIR_TARGET` is associated with the specified target of the rule in which it appears.

Comment: I have no idea about any of this. I've looked for `LIBAPP` and `LIBFLAGS`. There is no mention of `LIBAPP` anywhere in the project or Qt install directory. `LIBFLAGS` appear only in context of `QMAKE_LIBFLAGS` and are never really set to anything.
Where do I fill it? With what? Why isn't is set already?

How do I even start do deal with this?

Comment: You'll have to ask a qt or qmake person.  This is all internal to their build system, it has nothing to do with make or makefiles in general.  Hopefully some people who know about this will come along.

Comment: LIBAPP is indeed unset. But just for this project, it works fine for it's dependency. My initial search for the symbol had failed me. I hate everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that `LIBAPP` is indeed unset. Why that is the case, I don't know. It's dependency, using the same kit and compiler has it set just fine.

Solution I employed is to just set `LIBAPP` to, in my case, `llvm-lib /NOLOGO`.

I absolutely hate everything about this.